# classifying circle markers by color in leaflet R and adding legend

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I have a data frame like `c = (lat, lng, decile)` which decile has ten levels. obviously, by ggmap and ggplot we can plot some points in given (lat,lng) as if we set `color` argument to decile column in `geom_point` it will classify the points and add legend automatically. But, I used leaflet to shoe the map. using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824893/coloring-continuous-data-in-leaflet-r-does-not-work?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I have written this code:

```
pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = colorRampPalette(rainbow(10))(length(c$decile)), 
  domain = c$decile)
```

`c %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addCircleMarkers(color = ~ pal(deciles))`

and I have points on my map in ten colors. so, my question has two parts:
-is there a simple way like ggplot to classify colors in the leaflet?
-how can I add a legend for these ten colors? in `addLegend(labels , colors)` how should I fix the arguments?

UPDATE:
this is my `c`

`> head(c)
       lat      lon decile
1 35.68705 51.38176      4
2 35.80742 51.48610      6
3 35.69151 51.39816      5
4 35.66665 51.35095      2
5 35.77566 51.40209      7
6 35.70326 51.41348      8`

Comment: We don't have access to `c`. Can you add it to your post?

Comment: I updated my question and added `c` dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not totally sure I understand the question, but if I do, the gist is: you are currently using a continuous palette, but you want this to be 10 discrete categories, and you want a legend for this, is that right?

In that case can you not just use colorFactor() instead of colorNumeric()?

So like:

```
pal <- colorFactor(
   palette = colorRampPalette(rainbow(10))(length(c$decile)), 
   domain = c$decile)
```

And then

```
   leaflet(c) %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(lng=c$lon, lat=c$lat, color = ~pal(decile)) %>% 
    addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal, values = ~decile,
            title = "Deciles")
```

Is that what you were after?